# Not getting the file extension right when serving a file

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, download

I havs a Spring MVC application and users can request files. Here's how I serve the files:

```
public HttpEntity<byte[]> getFile (byte [] archivoBytes, String name, String extension) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", extension));
    headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
    headers.setContentLength(archivoBytes.length);

    return new HttpEntity<>(archivoBytes, headers);

}
```

My variable name is correct and contains the file name with extension. When I try to download the file though, if I tell firefox to "open with", my file will open with the default (in this case) pdf editor, but if I download the file, it will have no extension and I will have to manually add the extension. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just Windows that are not showing file extensions in the Explorer? Try opening a command prompt and run `dir` in the given folder.

Comment: No, when I try to open it after downloading, besides not showing my pdf editor icon, doesn't know how to open it

Comment: The file name needs to be quoted. See e.g. [`Content-Disposition` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

Comment: Yes, gonna edit my answer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, my filename contained white spaces that couldn't be parsed, so if my file name was "math exam.pdf", when I downloaded the file the file name would be "math".

The soultion is to use escape quotes to surround the file name, like this:

```
headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + name + "\"");
```